How to send ViewModel event on activity start in the ViewModel init function correctly?
I want a camera screen to open after the activity has been created. When I send an event triggering the camera in the ViewModel init function then nothing happens:
The ViewModel init function:
init{
  viewModelScope.launch {
                _eventFlow.emit(
                    UiEvent.TakePhoto
                )
            }
}

The function triggering the camera in the activity:
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
            {
                viewModel.eventFlow.collectLatest { event ->
                    when(event){
                        is PhotoViewModel.UiEvent.TakePhoto ->
                        {
                            takePhoto()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private fun takePhoto()
    {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        resultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)
    }

But when I add a delay in the init function then it works:
init{
  viewModelScope.launch {

                    delay(1000)

                _eventFlow.emit(
                    UiEvent.TakePhoto
                )
            }
}

Is there any more correct solution to this?

What is _eventFlow? If it is something like a MutableSharedFlow, then the event can be emitted before the activity enters the RESUMED state and is in position to observe that event. "I want a camera screen to open after the activity has been created" -- why do you need your viewmodel to be involved in this? For that matter, why are you starting an activity (the one with the repeatOnLifecycle() call), then immediately starting another activity (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)?

Use collect instead of collectLatest ensures that every emission is handled, and since there's only one emission happening immediately after the ViewModel is created, it ensures that the collection is completed without being cancelled.
       lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                mainViewModel.takePhotoEvent.collect {
                    takePhoto()
                }
            }
        }

